# Jenkins OSS LTS upgrade from 2.319.3 to 2.375.2

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins OSS version right now is 2.319.3, the LTS version we are trying to upgrade to is 2.375.2. Is it advisable to this upgrade directly. Will there be any major breakages if we do this update ?

Yet to try the update, as this is a production machine did not want to break anything.

Comment: 1) never just upgrade production, unless it means nothing to you. Take a backup, spin up the backup, read the upgrade guides and Changing. Upgrade all plugins, upgrade to next major LTS last point increase, upgrade plugins, test. Repeat for each major LTS to latest. Then backup produce and do it there. Or just wing it.

Comment: @IanW Thanks for replying, right now our Jenkins is installed in a EC2 machine, could you tell me how I can move to a docker new version and import all my jobs. If you could point me to a step-by-step guide to building the Dockerfile and importing all the jobs that would be great.

Comment: I don't use EC2 and my instance is VM hosted w/Docker agents. Depends on how you've set up your [Docker/Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/) combo, what iamges/packages you've used as to what the steps are. Read [here](https://www.jenkins.io/solutions/docker/). If you used a package installer, you don't want to [manually update](https://gist.github.com/ricardo-dlc/1a6cbd9d48e4fa791b022b1eebc15de5).. Lots of people [post sol'ns](https://batmat.net/2018/09/07/how-to-run-and-upgrade-jenkins-using-the-official-docker-image/). Help in https://community.jenkins.io/tag/docker.